# How can I update my version of `unzip` to version 6.00 or higher?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, zip, archive-utility

Its a common problem that, when unzipping (read: 'open by double-click'), some `.zip` files result in a similar sized `.cpgz` file. But you expected an unzipped file or folder instead.

The default unzip program in OS X is '/System/Library/CoreServices/Archive Utility.app'

When you try to unzip it in the Terminal (`/usr/bin/unzip`) you see the following:

```
$ unzip SE.zip

Archive:  SE.zip
warning [SE.zip]:  zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
  attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
  together in order.  Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support
  doesn't exist yet (coming soon).
error [SE.zip]:  missing 8256083459 bytes in zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [SE.zip]:  attempt to seek before beginning of zipfile
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

I have Mavericks 10.9.5 running, and a `unzip -v` learns us we are on version 5.52:

```
$ unzip -v
UnZip 5.52 of 28 February 2005, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler. Send
bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.
...
```

The funny thing is, the same 'corrupt' zip file extracts fine on my CentOS system. There is no error and the file seems fine. My CentOS system runs unzip version 6.00:

```
$ unzip -v
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Send
bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.
...
```

My question: How can I update my version of `unzip` to version 6.00 or higher?

And affiliated question: Will my new version of OS X unzip also have affect on the default unzip 'Archive Utility.app'?

ps. *I prefer the use of a package manager like `brew` above compiling from source. `brew install unzip` results in: `Error: No available formula for unzip`*

Comment: Use macports it does have unzip version 6.0 :)

Comment: ha ha brew vs. macports... I have my system already marinaded with brew. But mightbe I can check the source. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Was your "affiliated" question answered? *"Will my new version of OS X unzip also have affect on the default unzip 'Archive Utility.app'?"* I was wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Homebrew (as requested):

```
$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
$ brew install unzip
```

This will install unzip at (considering defaults) `/usr/local/Cellar/unzip/6.0/bin/unzip`

You can then alias it as `unzip6` somewhere in your path.

Also, you may want to to try ["The Unarchiver"](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353) from the app store. Much more useful IMO then Apple's Archive Utility.

**UPDATE**

dupes has been deprecated in Homebrew, so `brew tap homebrew/dupes` is no longer necessary. All you need now (assuming Homebrew is installed) is:

```
brew install unzip
```

Then you can add a link to `/usr/local/bin` with:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/unzip/bin/unzip /usr/local/bin/unzip6
```

Now the system `unzip` should work with `unzip` and Version 6 will work with `unzip6`

Comment: I was missing the `brew tap homebrew/dupes`. No clue what is does but now I *can* do a brew install unzip. thnx a bunch.

Comment: Although I now have a working unzip 6.0.0, just like I wanted, now I have a new error. Mightbe you can help me with it, but it is beyond this topic. `skipping: foobar  need PK compat. v4.5 (can do v2.1)` for each file in the zip.

Comment: Can't solve the problem, though my guess is the file was zipped using PKZip and it did something... *unique*

Comment: BTW the tap command opens up new apps in brew that are left out of the default for various reasons (specifically is adds new specific homebrew git repo's). This includes things like `dupes`, `games`, and `php` etc.

Comment: In case anyone gets to this page because they're getting an error unzipping large zip files, go with The Unarchiver in the link. Worked for me.

Comment: This noob wants to know: What do you mean when you say, *"You can then alias it as unzip6 somewhere in your path."?* Why would someone want to do that? If someone does it, how would the alias be used going forward?

Comment: @EJMak Using The Unarchiver app may be your best bet. That said... When Homebrew installs something already part of MacOS (i.e. `unzip`), it will not *link* it so it is easily useable. In the case of `unzip` Homebrew will install it to `/usr/local/opt/unzip/bin/unzip`. To create an *alias* or a *link* you use the following command (from the command line (terminal.app)) `ln -s /usr/local/opt/unzip/bin/unzip /usr/local/bin/unzip6`. Assuming /usr/local/bin is in your path, you can use `unzip6` from the command line to use this, or `unzip` to use the Mac default.

Answer (score 3):

You may find that [p7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) does what you want. Use `brew install p7zip` to install, then run `7z -h` to get some help.

I'm using `7z t` on a 20GB zipfile as I write this, to test its integrity. Both Unzip 5.52 and Unzip 6.0 choked on it.

Comment: Yes! E.g. p7zip works very nicely to uncompress Microsoft's IE VM images, which are 5 GB+.

Comment: Cool, but it doesn't answer the question.